# reg expression / search and replace to simulate paste command of unix

Tags: windows, unix, paste, regexp-replace

if i have a file

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

is there a search and replace / reg expr / cli that can produce

```
a a
b b
c c
d d
e e
```

i know the unix command paste does it but I am in a locked down environment on windows.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the file *sample.txt*, with each line ending in a newline:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

The following line run at a command prompt will produce "result.txt" with the output you want:

```
for /f %i in (sample.txt) do echo %i %i >> result.txt
```

The `for` loop reads each line in the input file, assigns it to the variable `%i`, and then echos that variable twice, appending the output via redirection to the output file. To use in a batch file, double the percent sign before each use of the variable `i`, as in `%%i`.

Typing `for /?` or `help for` at a command prompt will provide you with more information about use of that command.